# A question about partial derrivaive

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

In calculus, we are introduced about the partial derivatives, like for example
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial(x^2-y)}{\partial x}(x,y),\ \ \ \frac{\partial(x+e^y-yz)}{\partial y}(x,y,z),\ \ \ \frac{\partial(x+y)}{\partial(x+y)}(x,y)\ \ ...
\end{align}
But I wonder if these sort of derivatives
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial(ax+by)}{\partial(cx+dy)}(x,y),\ \ \ \frac{\partial(ax+by+cz)}{\partial(dx+ey+fz)}(x,y,z) \ \ ...
\end{align}
are exists in math ? And if they are valid, then what are their explicit value ? Or even more generally, is something like $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)}{\partial g(x_1,\cdots,x_n) }$ exists in math ? My guess, if they are valid, then they can be identified as
$$  \frac{\partial f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)}{\partial g(x_1,\cdots,x_n) } = \frac{\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i }(x_1,\cdots,x_n)  }{\displaystyle   \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i }(x_1,\cdots,x_n)   }$$
but I am not sure.

I hope someone will help me to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: Please say explicitly where "we" have such a collection of nonsense symbols.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I mean those symbols are just for example. What I wonder is if there is such thing like $\displaystyle\frac{\partial(ax+by) }{\partial(cx+dy) } $ in math, or even more generally, is something like $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)}{\partial g(x_1,\cdots,x_n) }$ exists in math. My guess, if they are valid, then they can be identified as
$$  \frac{\partial f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)}{\partial g(x_1,\cdots,x_n) } = \frac{ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i }(x_1,\cdots,x_n)  }{  \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i }(x_1,\cdots,x_n)   }$$
but I am not sure.

Comment: In my answer I have indicated that this would only be unambiguous if we simultaneously  changed the variables to $g_1(x_1,\dots, x_n),\dots, g_n(x_1,\dots, x_n)$. Essentially I think there are better ways to formalise what you want, the partial derivative notation can be ambiguous and misleading. Look also at Phluffy's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may be looking for the directional derivative $D_{\boldsymbol{v}}f(\boldsymbol{p})$ for $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R^n}$. This is morally a measure of how much $f$ grows or decays as the inputs of $f$ move away from $\boldsymbol{p}$ in the direction of $\boldsymbol{v}$.

Formally, given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ we define the directional derivative of $f$ at $\boldsymbol{p}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ in the direction of $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to be
$$D_\boldsymbol{v}f(\boldsymbol{p) := }\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(\boldsymbol{p}+t\boldsymbol{v}) - f(\boldsymbol{p)}}{t}.$$One can show that the directional derivative is conveniently
$$D_\boldsymbol{v}f(\boldsymbol{p}) = \nabla f(\boldsymbol{p}) \cdot \boldsymbol{v}$$

Answer (score 1):

When we write $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ there is a hidden convention that this means the derivative *keeping $y$ constant.*

But if we wrote $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial (ax+by)}$ we would have a problem: there is no natural choice of what to keep  constant.

To  make things clear we have to explicitly change the pair of variables: for example $u:=ax+by, v:=23y^2+\cos xy$: then if we write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ the implication is that $v$ is being kept constant.

Comment: How about some special examples like $ \displaystyle\frac{ \partial\big( (x+y)^3  \big)}{ \partial(x+y)  }(x,y) $ ? Would that be $3(x+y)^2 $ or something else ?

Comment: I can't really understand why anyone would want to do this: playing with the notation is fun, but is there any mathematical significance to all this?

Comment: It came out from an issue when I tried to take the derivative $\displaystyle\frac{d(f\circ x^{-1}\circ x\circ c ) }{ dt} (t) $ where  
 $$ \mathbb R\overset{ c}{ \longrightarrow} \mathbb R^n  \xrightarrow{x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)}\mathbb R^n
 \overset{ x^{-1}}{ \longrightarrow}
 \mathbb R^n \overset{ f}{ \longrightarrow} \mathbb R $$
I just wonder why it becomes
$$\sum_1^n \frac{ \partial (f\circ x ^{-1})}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{x=x(c(t))}\big(x_i\circ c\big)'(t)$$ but not  $$\sum_1^n \frac{ \partial (f\circ x^{-1})}{\partial (x_i\circ c)} \bigg|_{x(c)=x(c(t)) }\big(x_i\circ c\big)'(t)$$